# A simple way to replace date created with last opened date?

Tags: snow-leopard, script

I have a huge number of files that were copied into an old OS X 10.6 server.  Problem is there are a large number that came over with a time last opened but no create or modified dates.  Is there a basic script to go through and change the create date to the last opened date?

Comment: Where do you see that they have no creation date?

Comment: Can you copy them again? If so, create a zip or tar file with them; then dates will be preserved

Comment: Sadly, no - this was done some time ago - and the problem is that the reporting tool is not designed to pick up anything other than Create and Modify :)  The lack of dates is apparent when queried in spotlight